# My location throw null pointer exception?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, geolocation, gps

Yesterday! i wrote code to find location! it's work.
but today, when i code more at diffirent function, it doesn't work. and throw an exception
Can you help me?? hix! i am newbie.
here is the log:

```
    11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at com.example.zzzzzz.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:351)
11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2205)
11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:777)
11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:532)
11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9112)
11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-26 09:44:52.109: E/AndroidRuntime(9259):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 09:44:53.939: I/Process(9259): Sending signal. PID: 9259 SIG: 9
```

and this is my function to find location:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.about:
        //about
        Intent about = new Intent("com.example.zzzzzz.About");
        startActivity(about);
        break;
    case R.id.setting:
        //setting
        Intent setting = new Intent("com.example.zzzzzz.Setting");
        startActivityForResult(setting, 2);
        break;
    case R.id.direction:
        //direction
        Intent direction = new Intent("com.example.zzzzzz.Direction");
        startActivityForResult(direction, 1);
        break;
    case R.id.MyLocation:
        //mylocation
        //Intent mylocation = new Intent("com.example.zzzzzz.MyLocation");
        //startActivity(mylocation);
        initLocationManagerV2();
        LocationManager locationManager;
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService (Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        GeoPoint find = new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1E6), (int)(lng*1E6));
        mv.getController().animateTo(find);
        mv.invalidate();
        break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

and this is the function initLocationMaganeV2 :

```
private void initLocationManagerV2() {
    locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locListener = new LocationListener() {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {
            createAndShowCustomOverlay(newLocation);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        }
    };
    locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
            locListener);
}

protected void createAndShowCustomOverlay(Location newLocation) {
    List overlays = mv.getOverlays();

    // first remove old overlay
    if (overlays.size() > 0) {
        for (Iterator iterator = overlays.iterator(); iterator
                .hasNext();) {
            iterator.next();
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

    // transform the location to a geopoint
    GeoPoint geopoint = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (newLocation.getLatitude() * 1E6), (int) (newLocation
                    .getLongitude() * 1E6));

    // Create new Overlay
    CustomOverlay overlay = new CustomOverlay(geopoint);

    mv.getOverlays().add(overlay);

    // move to location
    //mv.getController().animateTo(geopoint);

    // redraw map
    mv.postInvalidate();
}
```

Comment: What is line 351 of MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 0):

most probably

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

returns **null**, and you use it without checking.

Comment: `if( location != null ) {` do something with location here `}`, otherwise just ignore or show an error. GPS may not have a location if it was used long time ago or haven't got a satellite fix yet.

Answer (score 0):

The Google documentation on getLastKnownLocation(provider) states that "If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned."  Make sure your GPS is enabled any time you test your routine with the code above, as you have

```
locationManager.getLastKnownLocation (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```